# What Should I do to avoid code duplication in my methods in Service Layer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've problem with my code. I've service class with methods like add, update etc. In each method I retrieve information like authentication, from authentication username, from username User Object etc and I use this information to add new objects to my database without giving them manually but by token after login. It looks like below

```
 Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
 UserPrinciple userPrinciple = (UserPrinciple) authentication.getPrincipal();
 String username = userPrinciple.getUsername();
```

I am using this code in three methods in my Service class. What should I do to reduce it to one using?

Comment: Suppose that some time in future you have to change those lines. If you extract a method, you just modify that method. If you have copy-pasted code you have to modify every single copy of that code, and if you forget one of those lines who knows what can happen.

Comment: Take a look here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87696/is-copy-paste-programming-bad

Comment: The bigger problem is that you have hidden dependencies here. It's usually best to define a security boundary (often at the MVC controller level) and pass in the `UserPrincipal` to lower levels as a method parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
UserPrinciple userPrinciple = (UserPrinciple) authentication.getPrincipal();
String username = userPrinciple.getUsername();
```

to the separate method.

Example:

```
private String getUserName() {
    Authentication authentication = 
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserPrinciple userPrinciple = (UserPrinciple) authentication.getPrincipal();
    return userPrinciple.getUsername();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor out the common code/behavior to a method and invoke that method where ever necessary. In this case, just follow what @MZxFK has suggested. Redundancy is an open enemy to to writing good code